# Include a logo in a bill using srclttr2

Tags: letters, scrlttr2, header

I found the following template for writing bills:

```
\documentclass
  [fontsize=11pt,
   paper=a4,   
   headsepline=off,
   parskip=half,
   fromalign=right,
   fromphone=on,
   fromrule=aftername,
   fromfax=off,
   fromemail=on,
   fromurl=off,
   fromlogo=on,
   addrfield=on,
   backaddress=on,
   subject=beforeopening,
   locfield=narrow,
   foldmarks=on,
   numericaldate=off,
   refline=narrow,
   firstfoot=on,
   % Formatierung
   draft=off
]{scrlttr2}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[english, ngerman]{babel}  
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{colortbl}
% symbols: (cell)phone, email
\RequirePackage{marvosym} % for gray color in header
%\RequirePackage{color} % for gray color in header
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault} % Latin Modern Sans
\setkomafont{fromname}{\sffamily\color{mygray}\LARGE}
%\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\sffamily}
\setkomafont{subject}{\mdseries}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\mdseries}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small\sffamily\mdseries\color{mygray}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\LoadLetterOption{DIN}
\makeatletter
\@setplength{sigbeforevskip}{17mm}
\@setplength{firstheadvpos}{17mm} 
\@setplength{firstfootvpos}{275mm} 
\@setplength{firstheadwidth}{\paperwidth}
\@setplength{locwidth}{70mm}   
\@setplength{locvpos}{65mm}  
\ifdim \useplength{toaddrhpos}>\z@
  \@addtoplength[-2]{firstheadwidth}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\else
  \@addtoplength[2]{firstheadwidth}{\useplength{toaddrhpos}}
\fi
\@setplength{foldmarkhpos}{6.5mm}
\makeatother
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Farben werden hier definiert
% define gray for header
\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{.55}
% define blue for address
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.45,0.75}

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Absender Daten
\setkomavar{fromname}{MAX MUSTERMANN}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Musterstad \\ 12345}
\setkomavar{fromphone}[\Mobilefone~]{+49\,(0)\,123\,456\,789\,0}
%\setkomavar{fromfax}[\FAX~]{+49\,(0)\,123\,456\,789\,0}
\setkomavar{fromemail}[\Letter~]{max.mustermann@mustermail.com}
\setkomavar{fromurl}[]{https://max-mustermann.com}
%\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\small\rmfamily\mdseries\slshape\color{myblue}}

\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ - }
%\setkomavar{backaddress}{Max Mustermann, alternative Straße, alternative Stadt} 
\setkomavar{signature}{Max MUSTERMANN} 
% signature same indention level as rest
\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}
\setkomavar{location}{\raggedleft

}
% Anlage neu definieren
\renewcommand{\enclname}{Anlagen}
\setkomavar{enclseparator}{: }

%pagenumber=footmiddle
\pagestyle{plain}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%--------------------------------------------

\firstfoot{\footnotesize%
\rule[3pt]{\textwidth}{.4pt} \\
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}% 
\usekomavar{fromname}\\
\usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
\end{tabular}%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
  \usekomavar[\Mobilefone~]{fromphone}\\
   \usekomavar[\Letter~]{fromemail}\\
    \usekomavar{fromurl}\\
\end{tabular}%
\ifkomavarempty{frombank}{}{%
\hfill
\begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
Bankverbindung: \\
\usekomavar{frombank}
\end{tabular}%
}%
}% 
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Bankverbindung
\setkomavar{frombank}{Kto. 123456789\\
BLZ 123\,123\,12\\
Musterbank}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\setkomavar{yourref}{}
%\setkomavar{yourmail}{}
%\setkomavar{myref}{}
%\setkomavar{customer}{}
\setkomavar{invoice}{012010}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Datum und Ort werden hier eingetragen
\setkomavar{date}{\today}
\setkomavar{place}{Musterstadt}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------

%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Hier beginnt der Brief, mit der Anschrift des Empfängers

\begin{letter}
{
Maxi Musterfrau\\
Nebenstraße 1\\
12345 Musterhausen\\
}

\setkomavar{subject}{\textbf{RECHNUNG}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\opening{Sehr geehrte Frau Musterfrau,}

Bitte überweisen Sie den folgenden Rechnungsbeitrag innerhalb von 14 Tagen auf das unten angegebene Konto.

\vspace{5pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ccXrr}
\hline
%\rowcolor[gray]{.95}
\tiny {Menge} & \tiny {Einheit} & \tiny {Beschreibung} & \tiny {Einzelpreis (netto)} & \tiny {Gesamtpreis (netto)} \\ \hline
 10 & Std. & Musterbrief erstellt & \multicolumn{1}{r}{30,00 EUR} & \multicolumn{1}{r}{300,00 EUR} \\ \hline \hline
\multicolumn{ 4}{l}{\small{Summe ohne MwSt.}} & 300,00 EUR \\ \hline
\multicolumn{ 4}{l}{\small{MwSt. 19\% }} & 57,00 EUR \\ \hline \hline
\multicolumn{ 4}{l}{ \textbf{Gesamtsumme inkl. MwSt.} } & \textbf{357,00 EUR} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
%\ps{PS:}
%\cc{}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{letter}
%---------------------------------------------------------------------------
\end{document}
%---------------------------------
```

Now, I would really like to include a logo on the top right corner. I don't want the address, name etc. to be put there. I only want the backaddress line. Is there a way of achieving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want something like the following image?

[image]

For the logo in the header you have to add:

```latex
\usepackage{graphicx}
\setkomavar{firsthead}{\hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}}
```

MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[
  fontsize=11pt,
  parskip=half
]{scrlttr2}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{lmodern}
%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}% needed for older TeX distributions
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% replaced
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}% needed for the inclusion of the logo

\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\setplength{sigbeforevskip}{17mm}
\setplength{firstheadvpos}{17mm} 
\setplength{firstfootvpos}{275mm} 
\setplength{locwidth}{70mm}
\setplength{locvpos}{65mm}
\setplength{foldmarkhpos}{6.5mm}

\definecolor{mygray}{gray}{.55}% define gray for header
\definecolor{myblue}{rgb}{0.25,0.45,0.75}% define blue for address

% Absender Daten
\setkomavar{fromname}{MAX MUSTERMANN}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Musterstad \\ 12345}
\setkomavar{fromphone}[\Mobilefone~]{+49\,(0)\,123\,456\,789\,0}
\setkomavar{fromemail}[\Letter~]{max.mustermann@mustermail.com}
\setkomavar{fromurl}[]{https://max-mustermann.com}
\setkomavar{backaddressseparator}{ - }
\setkomavar{signature}{Max MUSTERMANN}
\setkomavar{frombank}{Kto. 123456789\\BLZ 123\,123\,12\\Musterbank}

\renewcommand*{\raggedsignature}{\raggedright}

\renewcaptionname{ngerman}{\enclname}{Anlagen}% renew enclosing name for ngerman

\setkomavar{firsthead}{\hfill\includegraphics[height=2cm]{example-image}}% logo in header

\setkomavar{firstfoot}{\footnotesize% deprecated command replaced
  \rule[3pt]{\textwidth}{.4pt} \\
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}% 
    \usekomavar{fromname}\\
    \usekomavar{fromaddress}\\
  \end{tabular}%
  \hfill
  \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
    \usekomavar[\Mobilefone~]{fromphone}\\
    \usekomavar[\Letter~]{fromemail}\\
    \usekomavar{fromurl}\\
  \end{tabular}%
  \ifkomavarempty{frombank}{}{%
    \hfill
    \begin{tabular}[t]{l@{}}%
      Bankverbindung: \\
      \usekomavar{frombank}
    \end{tabular}%
  }%
}% 

\begin{document}
\begin{letter}{Maxi Musterfrau\\Nebenstraße 1\\12345 Musterhausen}
\setkomavar{subject}{RECHNUNG}
\setkomavar{invoice}{012010}
\opening{Sehr geehrte Frau Musterfrau,}
Bitte überweisen Sie den folgenden Rechnungsbeitrag innerhalb von 14~Tagen auf das unten angegebene Konto.

\begingroup
\par
\medskip
\setlength{\parfillskip}{0pt plus 1fil}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ccXrr}
  \hline
  \tiny Menge & \tiny Einheit & \tiny Beschreibung & \tiny Einzelpreis (netto) & \tiny Gesamtpreis (netto) \\ \hline
   10 & Std. & Musterbrief erstellt & \multicolumn{1}{r}{30,00 EUR} & 300,00 EUR \\ \hline \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{l}{\small Summe ohne MwSt.} & 300,00 EUR \\ \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{l}{\small MwSt. 19\% } & 57,00 EUR \\ \hline \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{l}{ \textbf{Gesamtsumme inkl. MwSt.} } & \textbf{357,00 EUR} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
\par
\endgroup

\closing{Mit freundlichen Grüßen,}
\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

I have removed all the unused options and the options with default values and other unneeded code. Uptodate KOMA-Script versions provide `\setplength` and `\addtoplength`. `scrlttr2` loads letter class option `DIN` automatically. `\tiny` and `\small` are font switches, they do not take an argument. `\firstfoot{...}` should be replaced by `\setkomavar{firstfoot}{...}`.